# Получить данные из заданных ячеек Excel

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7

Имеется таблица в Excel. Из нее нужно выбрать каждую 50-ю ячейку (если она не пуста конечно же). Начинаем выбор с ячейки "B6". То есть следующая должна быть "В56"
Чтобы получить данные одной ячейки использую PHPExcel

```
$excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('vote-result.xls');
$StepCell = 50; // переменная для следующей ячейки

$NameOfDeсision = $excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B' . $CellOfDeсision)->getValue(); // получаем значение из одной ячейки
echo $NameOfDeсision;
```

но получается что для следующей ячейки мне уже нужны другие переменные

```
$CellOfDeсision1 = $CellOfDeсision+$StepCell; // увеличиваю значение ячейки на 50 (нужный мне шаг)
$NameOfDeсision1 = $excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B' . $CellOfDeсision1)->getValue(); // получаем значение из следующей ячейки
```

но сам понимаю, что это не нормально. Ведь я не знаю сколько на листе нужных мне результатов. Может быть 10, а может и 50. Помогите пожалуйста. Как правильно выбрать данные из excel?

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php

$excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('vote-result.xls');
$step = 50;
$column = 6;
do {
    $value = $excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B' . $column)->getValue();
    echo $value;
    $column += $step;
} while ($value);
```